# Do I need to run `nodetool upgradesstables` when upgrading from DSE 4.5 => 4.6?

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise

When upgrading Datastax Enterprise from 4.5 to 4.6, do I need to run `nodetool upgradesstables`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Nodetool upgradesstables` is meant for a major version of Cassandra.  Both DSE 4.5 and 4.6 use Cassandra 2.0 under the hood, so it is not necessary.  It won't hurt to run it though.

Answer (score 0):

The oldest 4.5 releases uses Cassandra 2.0.8.39, the latest 4.6.9 uses Cassandra 2.0.16.678. I wouldn't expect upgradesstables to be required unless:

- Major version changes (e.g. some versions of 1.x to 2.x)
- Compression settings change

I did a minor version upgrade (2.0 -> 2.1) in production recently and not running it wasn't causing any issues either.